# How to export custom post type details with it's postmeta and images

Tags: wordpress, import, export, wordpress-theming, wordpress-admin

I have a custom post type on two websites and I have to export all posts in that post type and import to the second site.

So my post type is **"products"**. Actually, I can use Wordpress default import export but the problem is that it is not including the full details in the post type and not exporting all images.

In my product, I have an additional image gallery section near featured image sidebar. Here I can add gallery images.

so if my **post id is 324** and I **added two galley images** for that post then in database post_meta_option I can see that

**post_id=324**, ***meta_key=rtthemert_gallery_images*** ,**meta_value =222,223**  here 223,224 are image id.

So please anyone can help me to make an export query for this gallery images only, so that when I import to the second site the gallery images also need to automatically added to that post.

Comment: Please refer this URL for media transfer and import, export  post meta "https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/moving-wordpress-site/".

Comment: Instead of making a custom query, you could install https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-export/ on your site and then export the posts that you want to export. Then install https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/ on the target site and simply import the exported posts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [WP all Export](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-export) to export and [WP all Import](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import) to import on the other site.
Both plugins are developed by the same company and they work great together.

The interface is pretty straightforward and easy to use.

I've been using it for years on some really large databases with a lot of required tweakings and I never had any issue.

Comment: actually i know this . But i am looking for the way they are doing this . Anyway thank you :)

Comment: if you want to import images you will have to go to pro version

Answer (score 0):

You can use [All-in-One WP Migration — WordPress Plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) for export and import both.

The interface of this plugins is really easy also you can use it for exporting the content on one website as well for importing on the other site and the other good thing is its free.

Answer (score 0):

Use Zippy, it's free.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/zippy/

It lets us export and import posts with featured images and post meta intact.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: I am not affiliated with Zippy.