# Importing +90K Posts to Custom Post Type in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently working on importing 90K+ posts to a Custom Post Type including Taxonomies and Meta Values. Since I'm running into several issues and questions, I would like to ask the community if anyone has experience with importing that amount of posts.

I read multiple posts about this topic, but i'm not 100% sure if I've found the good solution. My current setup for the import function is this:

```
function import() { 
    global $wpdb;

    if (!defined('WP_IMPORTING')) {
        define('WP_IMPORTING', true);
    }
    
    ini_set("memory_limit", -1);
    set_time_limit(0);
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    
    wp_defer_term_counting(true);
    wp_defer_comment_counting(true);
    
    $wpdb->query('SET autocommit = 0;');
    
    // register a function for execution on shutdown
    register_shutdown_function(function () {
        global $wpdb;
    
        $wpdb->query('COMMIT;');
        $wpdb->query('SET autocommit = 1;');
    
        wp_defer_term_counting(false);
        wp_defer_comment_counting(false);
    });

    foreach($x as $y => $z) {
        // check if current already exists
        $postExists = post_exists(…);
        
        if (!is_wp_error($postExists)) {
            $postId = wp_insert_post(…);

            // taxonomies
            if (isset(…)) {
                $term = term_exists(…);
                if($term) {
                    wp_set_post_terms(…);
                }
            }

            // meta values
            // do one query for multiple meta values
            $metaKeys = [];
            $metaKeys['key'] = 'value';
            …
            $customFields = [];
            $placeHodlers = [];
            $queryString = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ";
            foreach ($metaKeys as $key => $value) {
                array_push($customFields, $postId, $key, $value);
                $placeHodlers[] = "('%d', '%s', '%s')";
            }
            $queryString .= implode(', ', $placeHodlers);
            $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("$queryString ", $customFields));
        }
    }
    
    $wpdb->query('COMMIT;');
    $wpdb->query('SET autocommit = 1;');
    wp_defer_term_counting(false);
    wp_defer_comment_counting(false);
}
```

The import still fails often with endless processing.

Thanks!

Comment: My experience would be to batch them, you could chunk into groups of 1,000 and process multiple times. That way you aren't stressing the server. There's other concurrency approach (background processes, crons, queues) but depending on your control and exp doing chunks might be the best approach

Comment: The problem is here you're querying in your loop. Don't check the if post exists in loop. Take all posts which matched with your importing in one loop, then delete them all with loop, after you can create a new post without checking if there's exist post. It will speed it up. You can simulate this scenario with commenting the post_exists lines. After removed these lines, you'll see duplicated posts but it will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use plugins from WP Repository?
I found on StackOverflow similar with your question.

[How to export custom post type details with it's postmeta and images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50293161/10710040)

Also add `set_time_limit()` to higher value / unlimited for a while.